# Type mismatch. Required: Double Found: String kotlin in android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

i'm new to kotlin android studio,trying to update the textView with editText from data class and i used in editText "afterTextChanged" , created a setter function in data class with editable paramete, i can't convert double to string with editable, anyone help me out ?
here is function in data class

`fun setSize(editable: Editable) {size = editable.toString()}`

Answer (score 1):

Your `size` variable is (apparently) a `Double`, so you have to assign a `Double` value to it. You're doing `editable.toString()` which just gives you a `String` representation of your `Editable`'s contents.

You need to try and parse that as a `Double` with [`toDouble()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double.html) (which throws an exception if it's not a valid number) or [`toDoubleOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double-or-null.html) (which returns *null* if it's invalid).

Since it's (I assume) user-edited content you're parsing, and there's a good possibility they'll enter something that's *not* a valid number representation, you need to handle that possibility. I'd go with `toDoubleOrNull` since it's easier in Kotlin (there are lots of these `*OrNull` variants on functions for that reason):

```
fun setSize(editable: Editable) {
    // only runs the let block if the value is parsed
    editable.toString().toDoubleOrNull()?.let { size = it }
}
```

or if you're not familiar with `let`:

```
fun setSize(editable: Editable) {
    val double = editable.toString().toDoubleOrNull()
    if (double != null) size = double
}
```

Comment: cannot find flag:2
invalidate any flag:{6}  it gives me this error

Comment: ~  android:afterTextChanged="@{Text -> shoeListingsViewModel.shoe.setSize(Text)}"~
this in that editText , is there is any thing wrong with it ?

Comment: @Raven that's a separate issue, and I'm not familiar with data binding, sorry. All the examples I've seen use parentheses around the parameter though, like `@{(text) -> shoeListingsViewModel.shoe.setSize(text)}`